# Return Cell Based On Model Data In Switch Statement

Tags: ios, swift, model, collectionview, indexpath

I have a model that holds a bool value. I would like to return a UICollectionViewCell based on the value of the bool within the model using a switch statement. However, I am getting a casting error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'Project.FalseCell' (0x10077a9f0) to 'Project.TrueCell' (0x100777ef8).
```

I've checked the following;

1. I have registered my cells in `viewDidLoad`
2. I have unique identifiers for each cell type

What am I missing here?

```
// MODEL
struct Model {
    let bool: Bool
}

// CONTROLLER
let models = [Model]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let model = models[indexPath.item]
    
    switch model.bool {
    case true:
        let trueCell: TrueCell = listView.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: TrueCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TrueCell
        return trueCell
    case false:
        let falseCell: FalseCell = listView.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: FalseCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! FalseCell
        return falseCell
    }
}
```

Comment: as the error log, i think your TrueCell have problem: that it identifier when reuse will return   a cell of type FalseCell

Comment: Yes you are right I had declared the identifier using String(describing: Self) however, I had renamed the custom cell class which had disturbed the identifier.

Comment: so if you had your answer, you should update the question with the answer and close this question

Comment: Definitely casting to FalseCell is causing error. Check your FalseCell if its of FalseCell type.

Answer (score 0):

As per @goat_herd 's comment, there was an issue with using cell identifiers as `String(describing: Self)` as I had renamed the Class at one point and this caused a disruption in the identifier.

I changed the identifier to a raw valued string and this solved the issue.